# Unix — grepping for a value at the start of a line

Tags: unix

Having a data as below and i am trying to take the fourth value of each line(delimited by :) for 1st value.
 But as 1st value is available in second line as well, it is giving me issue as below.

```
$ cat sample.txt 
MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT1:mulconfield:lt,ge,ge,ge,ge,ge:MSG_KENAN_KPAYDDT1 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT2 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT4 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT5 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT6 
MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3:mulconfield:le,ge,ge,ge:MSG_KENAN_KPAYDDT3 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT4 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT5 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT6
$

$ grep MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3 sample.txt|cut -d: -f4
MSG_KENAN_KPAYDDT1 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT2 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT4 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT5 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT6
MSG_KENAN_KPAYDDT3 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT4 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT5 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT6
$
```

You can see MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3 at first line also. I need only the line having my search string at 1st position.

But my expected output is

```
MSG_KENAN_KPAYDDT3 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT4 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT5 MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT6
```

because I want fourth value based on value (MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3) at 1st position.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3 at the start of line, say so:

```
grep '^MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT' sample.txt
```

The caret `^` at the beginning means 'if the following pattern appears at the beginning of the line'.

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative you can try with awk

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "MSG_KENAN_KBILLDT3") {print $4}  }' FS=":" sample.txt
```